Не вводится второе значение nodejs
Начинал изучать js(nodejs). Пробую написать простенькую программу. Не понимаю, почему второй ввод данных (ввод степени) не происходит: вопрос задается(Введите степень) после чего программа завершается.
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    }
)
rl.question("Введите число\n", (number) => {
    rl.question("Введите степень\n", (degree) => {
        if (numer < 1 || degree < 1) {
            console.log("Не поддреживается меньше 1")
        }
        console.log(pow(number, degree));
    })
    rl.close();
})
function pow (num, step) {
    let result = num;
    for(let i = 1; i < step; i++) {
        result = result * num;
    }
    return result;
}


Для начала numer -> number. Ну и проверка у вас идет на число, а с ввода вернется строка(скорее всего), надо преобразовать в число полученное значение

у вас так происходит потому что rl.close() вызывается до того как будет получен ответ на rl.question("Введите степень\n" и, следовательно, до того как будет вызван её колбек

При математических операциях, за исключением сложения строки приводятся к числам автоматически. Благодарю за подсказки. Разместил rl.close() перед return() пока, буду изучать асинхронность.

при математических операциях строки приводятся к числу, если это возможно согласно правилам приведения. сравните результат Number('   1  ') и Number('   1a')

используйте parseFloat/parseInt для чуть менее строго приведения
